# Opencart Add to Cart not working properly

Tags: opencart

the add to cart of opencart homepage is not working properly, whenever the products are added to the cart, every time I need to refresh the page manually to get the count of products added in the cart. also after deleting the products from cart again i need to refresh the page to get the quantity. but the same  product compare, wishlist and the add to cart of product page works fine without any problem. am using the opencart 2.1.0.1

Comment: you need to check the `F12` > `Developer Tools` `Network` Tab of your browser, check the response of that `AJAX/XHR` call. See if there is any warning/error coming up, which may cause the automatic ui refresh to stop. you can start there to debug.

Comment: check your opencart error log in admin panel to know the error